# Shutter stucks on manual mode

Tags: canon-60d

I bought a camera 60 d with only 1000 shutters. In the beginning i am having some issues with battery timing. Now i am facing another problem that on manual mode my shutter stucks in upward direction. But it auto mode it works perfectly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to photo.se. Could you please share your settings for manual mode?

Comment: Iso auto shutter speed 1/14 aperture  f/8

Comment: But i tried different manual settings like increasing the shutter speed changing aperture iso but it didn't work

Comment: Can you describe the "issues with battery timing"?

Comment: What exactly happens when the shutter sticks?

Comment: Yeah as i researched the battery timing of 60 d is about 1150 shoot. But with my battery i got 200 300 shoots. When i switched to live mode i hardly takes 10 15 shots. Then it turned of by showing empty battery. And if i turned on after switching it off the camera works normally show full battery.

Comment: Like normally when we click the shot shutter moved upward and comes back to its original position. But when i am on manual mode it just go upward and stuck there. And when i switched to auto mode it works perfectly

Comment: It seems that your battery is dead. Consider buying another one. No idea on the shutter problem.

Comment: Do you mean the the shutter or the *mirror*? How are you seeing that it is stuck?

Comment: Sounds like shutter speed may be set very slow (like 30 secs) on manual mode.

Comment: It's the sensor

Comment: What do you mean by "it's the sensor"? What is the sensor?

Comment: Keep a few dozen shutters as spares, sell the rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the behaviour you describe, I definitely think your battery is dead. It doesn't explain your "shutter" problem.

Comment: Made my comment an answer so OP can acknowledge it instead of responding with an not informative answer.

Comment: It's hard to write an informative answer to a question that is clear as mud. Both answers are possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have "mirror lockup" enabled. In "Auto" mode, the setting selected for mirror lockup will be ignored. In Manual exposure mode, it will be complied with.